# Find the equation in $S'$ of the plane whose equation is $2x - 3y + z = 2$

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Consider in $\mathbb{R}^3$ two reference systems $S = (O; \vec{e}_1, \vec{e}_2, \vec{e}_3)$ and $S' = (O'; \vec{e}'_1, \vec{e}'_2, \vec{e}'_3)$ with $OO' = (-2, 3, 9)$ in $S$, $\vec{e}'_1 = \vec{e}_1 + 3\vec{e}_2 + \vec{e}_3$, $\vec{e}'_2 = -\vec{e}_1$ and $\vec{e}'_3 = 2\vec{e}_1 + 5\vec{e}_2 + 7\vec{e}_3$. Find the equation in $S'$ of the plane whose equation is $2x -3y + z = 2$.

I have no idea how to go about this except for the steps in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip3nq.png)  picture.

Comment: Hint: normal vectors are covariant, so if points transform according to $p'=Mp$, where $M$ is some matrix, then plane normals transform according to $M^{-T}$.

Comment: @amd So in this case $\begin{bmatrix}1&3&1\\-1&0&0\\2&5&7\end{bmatrix}p = p'$. We also have that $\vec{n} = (2,-3,1)$ is a normal to the given plane. So then what do I do?